# Suffer from jdk version compatibility issue with jdk8 compiler though targetCompatibility is 1.7 already

Tags: java, gradle

We found a problem that a `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown when calling our lib's method which calls `keySet()` method in `ConcurrentHashMap` :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at cn.webank.wemq.client.impl.producer.MessageQueueHealthManager.fetchQueuePermFromNameserver(MessageQueueHealthManager.java:95)
    at cn.webank.wemq.client.impl.producer.ProducerFactory.publish(ProducerFactory.java:513)
    at cn.webank.wemq.client.impl.producer.ProducerFactory.publish(ProducerFactory.java:493)
    at cn.webank.wemq.producer.WeMQProducer.publish(WeMQProducer.java:147)
    at cn.webank.rmb.common.WeMQUtil.sendPersistentMsg(WeMQUtil.java:34)
    at cn.webank.rmb.core.impl.WeMQAsyncMessagePublisher.publish(WeMQAsyncMessagePublisher.java:50)
    at cn.webank.rmb.core.impl.WeMQClientImpl.publish(WeMQClientImpl.java:195)
    at cn.webank.rmb.impl.RMBWeMQImpl.publish(RMBWeMQImpl.java:124)
    at cn.webank.rmb.api.RMB.publish(RMB.java:97)
    at com.webank.multicase.BroadCastModePublisher$1.run(BroadCastModePublisher.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Since we use jdk8 as our development env, and compatibility issue considered, we will provide a version for jdk7. So we have already declare 
`sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` as 1.7 like

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    clean.doFirst {
        delete 'build'
        delete 'dist'
    }
    if (project.findProperty("jdk") == "1.7") {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        targetCompatibility = 1.7
    } else {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
        version = version + "-jdk8"
    }
    if (project.findProperty("snapshot") instanceof String) {
        if (project.property("snapshot").toBoolean()) version = version + "-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
```

And according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html, the byte code should be generated in  version of Java version 7.

Why this problem still occurs.

If I add

```
compileJava.options.bootClasspath = "$System.env.JAVA_HOME_7/jre/lib/rt.jar"
```

to use java7 compiler, the problem will be solved.

Question:

1. Then what is the actually usage of `targetCompatibility` if it is not actually make it compatible.
2. But this force us has installed jdk7 in our dev env. Is there a perfect solution for this?

Comment: It sets the bytecode version that the compiler generates, but can't know which of the classes and methods exict in that version and which don't.

Comment: Would you please put it more detail and have some refs in answer. I would expect that if target is 1.7, then everything should be using 1.7. If not, then what's the point of using 1.7? Only to check if the method or class exist?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID

Answer (score 0):

Please try to pass a project as an argument into an **allprojects** closure like in the example bellow, because by default project is a reference to a project within current **build.gradle** file, if we pass an argument it will be a concrete instance of a project to which configuration will be applied:

```
allprojects { prj ->
    if (prj.findProperty("jdk") == "1.7") {
        prj.sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        prj.targetCompatibility = 1.7
    } else {
        prj.sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        prj.targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}
```